# Attribute error on csv reader range

Tags: python, csv

I have the following code which should iterate though my csv file and create my json output. However, I am getting an attribute error on my exampledata object that no rows or row attribute exists. I know I can specify a specific row and column via [0][0] but need to dynamically call the row in the for loop vs specifically calling it. What can I do to fix this, is there a specific "row" or index I can use instead ie: exampledata[i][0]?

```
    payloads = []
    users_dict = {'users': []}
    exampleFile = open('zdfile-test.csv')
    exampleReader = csv.reader(exampleFile)
    exampleData = list(exampleReader)

    for row in range(1, exampleData.row):
      if exampleData(row)[2]:
        users_dict['users'].append(
            {
            "name": exampleData(row)[0],
            "email": exampleData(row)[2],
            "external_id": exampleData(row)[3],
            "details": exampleData(row)[4],
            "notes": exampleData(row)[5],
            "phone": exampleData(row)[6],
            "role": exampleData(row)[7],
            "organization_id": "",
            "tags": exampleData(row)[10],
            "password": exampleData(row)[11],
            "user_fields": {"nickname": exampleData(row)[1],"employee_phone_number": exampleData(row)[12],"employee_id": exampleData(row)[13],"employee_title": exampleData(row)[14],"employee_department": exampleData(row)[15],"employee_manager": exampleData(row)[16],"associate_id": exampleData(row)[17],"office_status": exampleData(row)[18],"customer_class": exampleData(row)[19],"primary_title": exampleData(row)[20],"associate_status": exampleData(row)[21],"joined_date": exampleData(row)[22],"e_mail": exampleData(row)[23],"isp_e_mail": exampleData(row)[24],"mobile": exampleData(row)[25],"office_name": exampleData(row)[26],"office_id": exampleData(row)[27],"office_city": exampleData(row)[28],"office_state": exampleData(row)[29],"office_phone": exampleData(row)[30],"region": exampleData(row)[31],"region_id": exampleData(row)[32],"region_type": exampleData(row)[33]}
        },
        {
            "external_id": exampleData(row)[3],
            "email": exampleData(row)[23],
        }
    )
```

Comment: can you post the Attribute Error.  If exampleData is a list, then it doesn't have an attribute row.

Comment: As @GarrettR says, a list doesn't have a row attribute. You can do instead: `for row in range(1, len(exampleData)):`

Comment: of course, then everywhere he's got exampleData(row) needs to be changed to exampleData[row].  But I think the problem is more fundamental than that.  Can you post a few lines of the `zdfile-test.csv`?

Comment: In the following line there will also be an error. Instead do: `exampleData[row][2]`

Comment: Bernie, that worked, thanks! Garrett, the error was: for row in range(1, exampleData.row):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'row'

Comment: Bernie, how do I give you the answer point? not seeing that for comments?

Comment: @user3691635: I've posted an answer so you can give it a point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @GarrettR says, a list doesn't have a row attribute. You can do instead:

```
for row in range(1, len(exampleData)):
    #               ^^^
```

In the following line there will also be an error so you can do:

```
if exampleData[row][2]:
#             ^   ^
```